# How to add multiple columns into single column or list

Tags: r

I have 21 columns of numerical data which I'd like to just collect into a single, really long column. How can I achieve this easily?

Comment: Do you mean as `as.vector` does?

Comment: `as.vector` works with `matrix` only

Answer (score 0):

See [apply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html).

You could do this:

```
vector <- apply(data, 2, c)
```

vector will be the columns of data joined by `c` function

Answer (score 0):

```
vector <- do.call(c, as.data.frame(a))
```

This will help. You transform your data to the `data.frame`, then apply colwise concatenation.

Comment: You can use ?unlist() or ?stack() unlist(data.frame(a))

Comment: Yes, it is really a simpler solution